# Symfony pages loading from cache

Tags: php, caching, symfony1

Im working on symfony project i got strange problem in production envirment. when i load the page it always getting to cache any dynamic data are not loading to the page. when i clear the cache browser its getting fixed data display correctly

my configuration in symfony config files cache false my application currently hosted in cloud envirment

My symfony config file `cache.yml` settings here

```
  default:
      enabled:     off
      with_layout: false
      lifetime:    86400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple Solution  is

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

put it your symfony web/index.php top

Answer (score 1):

From the Symfony [guide](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/12-Caching)

> **Global Cache Settings**
>
> For each application of a project, the HTML cache mechanism can be
>   enabled or disabled (the default), per environment, in the cache
>   setting of the settings.yml file. Listing 12-1 demonstrates enabling
>   the cache.
>
> Listing 12-1 - Activating the Cache, in frontend/config/settings.yml

```
prod:
  .settings:
    cache:                  off
```

Comment: no luck then my application redirected to login page every time